# Python How can I print a list with strings and intergers to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my list

```
[('Doctor', 1), ('Paramedic', 2), ('Janitor', 3)]
```

I want to print the list to a text file so it will look like this,

```
('Doctor', 1), ('Paramedic', 2), ('Janitor', 3)
```

or something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

simplest way to do it is to `convert list to string` and `remove parenthesis` using `slicing` and `write it to file`

No need of any `loop`

```
a = [('Doctor', 1), ('Paramedic', 2), ('Janitor', 3)]
a = str(a)[1:-1]
f = open("demofile2.txt", "a")
f.write(str(a))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a possible solution:

```py
LST = [('Doctor', 1), ('Paramedic', 2), ('Janitor', 3)]
OUTPUTFILE = "out.txt" # text file path

with open(OUTPUTFILE, "w") as f:
    for name, count in LST:
        f.write(f"{name}: {count}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
some_list = [('Doctor', 1), ('Paramedic', 2), ('Janitor', 3)]

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    for item in some_list:
        file.write(f'{item}, ')
```